# Postman basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, request, postman

I don't have great experience with authentication, for the moment I've created a simple MVC application with basic authentication(MVC creates all of it when you select `Individual User Accounts`). It works good, I've configured it globally so the app forces the user to be authenticated in order to access to anything, it works good, you can `Register` and then you can Login using the registered `username` and `password`. The thing is that I'm trying to make some requests using Postman and I get a `200 OK Status` but I'm getting always the `Login` page and I'm never getting the `json` data I want to... even if I'm selecting Basic Authentication in Postman and entering the `username` and `password` already registered...
Is it possible authenticate with postman, make a request and get `json` data that I am returning from one controller?

[image]

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you are doing wrong and why this is not working... Are you getting an input message asking for user and password when accessing the website using a browser?

Comment: Use some other tools like SOAP UI as your service client. Postman sometimes behave abnormally. do you have any login page or cookies? the logic of browsers in basic authentication is sending basic authentication credentials in every request.